# Leaflet - display rotated text with svg

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet

I'm trying to display text in Leaflet using a marker layer with icon as L.divIcon (with svg text). This works fine. However when the text is rotated the text is clipped outside the viewport. I've tried to adjust this in several ways, but to no avail. For example, I've tried to extract the BBox after rotation, and then update the svg viewBox parameters, but this doesn't work as expected.

Here you can see the viewbox of the svg containing rotated text. The text content **125BET** is clipped. The text **10665** is barely rotated, and is displayed correctly.

[image]

Here is the viewbox of the text component, and I want to use this information to avoid clipping:

[image]

Code:

```
let svgIcon = L.divIcon({
  html: `
<svg
  version="1.1"
  id="${svgGcTextId}"
  preserveAspectRatio="none"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>
  <text width="5000" height="5000" x="0" y="${fontSize}" transform="rotate(${rotation})" font-size="${fontSize}">${text}</text>
</svg>`,
  className: "",
  iconSize: [24, 10],
  iconAnchor: [0, fontSize],
});

let marker = L.marker(latlng, { icon: svgIcon, interactive: false });
```

**Edit**:

Tried adding transform-origin as per Peters suggestion. Although this seems to work, it shifts the insertion point of the text which isn't desirable. See pic below, where the "1" in **125BET** is translated south of the building. It's possible to see more of the text though, as more of it is inside the viewbox.

[image]

**Edit2**:

Here is a fiddle. Change the rotation and fontSize values to test different scenarios. Note that I have code for scaling the font size when zooming (but that shouldn't be relevant here)

https://jsfiddle.net/6vw5z20k/20/

**Edit3 - solved**

Thanks to Peters input I managed to solve it with the following code. It was necessary to specify a large viewbox (e.g. 600 x 600), then insert the text in the center using x and y. It was also necessary to specify the transform-origin, so the rotation was performed correctly. Last but not least the svg had to be centered at the reference latlng using iconAnchor.

```
const svgIcon = L.divIcon({
  html: `
<svg
  version="1.1"
  id="${svgGcTextId}"
  preserveAspectRatio="none"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  width="600"
  height="600"
>
  <text x="300" y="300" transform-origin="300 300" transform="rotate(${rotation})" font-size="${fontSize}">${text}</text>
</svg>`,
  className: "",
  iconSize: [24, 10],
  iconAnchor: [300, 300],
});

let marker = L.marker(latlng, { icon: svgIcon, interactive: false });
```

Lots of room to rotate the text 125BET here, but the viewbox might get to small if one zooms far in and the text is scaled too much.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally, I thought that all you needed to do was add: `transform-origin="120 60"` (or something similar) to the `<text>` element of your `svg` code.

However, once you updated your question, it appears that the problem may well be with setting the `height` and `width` on the `svg` itself.

You can still probably move the origin with `transform-origin` or just set the `x` and `y` on the `<text>` element.

Here is my code snippet (based on your jsFiddle). Please look for the rotated LONDON.

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution: '© OpenStreetMap'
}).addTo(map);

let fontSize = "60px";
let svgGcTextId = "";
let rotation = "45";
let text = "LONDON";
let latlng = [51.505, -0.09];

let svgIcon = L.divIcon({
  html: `
<svg
  version="1.1"
  id="${svgGcTextId}"
  preserveAspectRatio="none"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  width="300"
  height="300"
>
  <text width="5000" height="5000" x="30" y="30" transform="rotate(${rotation})" font-size="${fontSize}">${text}</text>
</svg>`,
  className: "",
  iconSize: [24, 10],
  iconAnchor: [0, 0],
});

let marker = L.marker(latlng, {
  icon: svgIcon,
  interactive: true
});
map.addLayer(marker);

let referenceMarker = L.circleMarker(latlng, {radius: 5});
map.addLayer(referenceMarker);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-hoalWLoI8r4UszCkZ5kL8vayOGVae1oxXe/2A4AO6J9+580uKHDO3JdHb7NzwwzK5xr/Fs0W40kiNHxM9vyTtQ==" crossorigin="" />
  <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-BB3hKbKWOc9Ez/TAwyWxNXeoV9c1v6FIeYiBieIWkpLjauysF18NzgR1MBNBXf8/KABdlkX68nAhlwcDFLGPCQ==" crossorigin=""></script>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding the viewbox. I will experiment with moving it/centering relative to the insertion point. I fear that I have to calculate a new latlng northwest of the insertion point to achieve this, based on how leaflet inserts markers/svgs.

Comment: thanks to your suggestions I managed to solve it now - much appreciated. I still have to figure out how to select a reasonable viewbox size though. I can make it gigantic, but that seems a bit too.. off :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also circumvent the need for `width` or `height` adjustments by setting a `overflow="visible"` attribute like so:

```
let svgIcon = L.divIcon({
  html: `
<svg
  version="1.1"
  id="${svgGcTextId}"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  overflow="visible"
>
  <text x="20" y="0" dy="${parseFloat(fontSize)*0.333}" transform="rotate(${rotation})" font-size="${fontSize}">${text}</text>
</svg>`,
  className: "",
  iconSize: [24, 10],
  iconAnchor: [0, 0],
});
```

Usually you would try to calculate a suitable width/height or viewBox to prevent colliding/overlapping svg elements.
For map usage it should work fine.

`x="20"` will add some space between your marker and the text.
`dy="${parseFloat(fontSize)*0.333}"` will give the text a baseline shift relative to the current `font-size`.

BTW: Neither width nor height attributes have any effects on a `<text>` element

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution: '© OpenStreetMap'
}).addTo(map);

let fontSize = "60px";
let svgGcTextId = "";
let rotation = "45";
let text = "LONDON";
let latlng = [51.505, -0.09];

let svgIcon = L.divIcon({
  html: `
<svg
  version="1.1"
  id="${svgGcTextId}"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  overflow="visible"
>
  <text x="20" y="0" dy="${parseFloat(fontSize)*0.333}" transform="rotate(${rotation})" font-size="${fontSize}">${text}</text>
</svg>`,
  className: "",
  iconSize: [24, 10],
  iconAnchor: [0, 0],
});

let marker = L.marker(latlng, {
  icon: svgIcon,
  interactive: true
});
map.addLayer(marker);

let referenceMarker = L.circleMarker(latlng, {radius: 5});
map.addLayer(referenceMarker);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 75vh;
}

.leaflet-map-pane svg {
    z-index: 200;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-hoalWLoI8r4UszCkZ5kL8vayOGVae1oxXe/2A4AO6J9+580uKHDO3JdHb7NzwwzK5xr/Fs0W40kiNHxM9vyTtQ==" crossorigin="" />
  <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-BB3hKbKWOc9Ez/TAwyWxNXeoV9c1v6FIeYiBieIWkpLjauysF18NzgR1MBNBXf8/KABdlkX68nAhlwcDFLGPCQ==" crossorigin=""></script>
    <div id="map"></div>
```